# How do I add variation strength between lights on an array modifier?

Tags: modifiers, lighting

I have parented several lights the face of an arrayed plane, all the lights are the same strength, is there a way to add different strengths to the lights with out having to individually change each light (there are about 50 lights and it would be a tedious task)

[image]

Comment: Hello ! If you're using Cycles, you can add custom shaders to the lights and I think you can vary the intensity there

Comment: @Gorgious I have to use even, its for a project. Do you know a way to do it in even?

Comment: @user142885: the name of the render engine is EEVEE ;)

Comment: why don't you use drivers?

Comment: @Chris it was a typo lol, how would I use a driver to add variation to the lighting strengths? Ive never used drivers but I only thought they were good for physical element.

Comment: Then you should watch some beginner tutorial about drivers and scripting. You will find out that you thought wrong and what amazing power they have.

Comment: Two times same typo…that’s magic ‍♂️